# Python Packaging: How does a package determine which source module is "__main__"?

Tags: python, package, program-entry-point

I am writing a Python 3 package, and I need to know how python determines which module is considered "**main**"? Is this something that is configured in `setup.py`, or some other file? Which setting in `setup.py` determines which module is called as `__main__`, like is it the `entry_points` attribute, or the `packages` attribute, or some other one?

Here is a simplified example of the package structure:

```
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── HISTORY.rst
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── mypackage
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mypackage.py
├── tests
│   └── test_mypackage.py
└── tox.in
```

So I just need to how how to set `__main__` to be the `mypackage.py` module or the `cli.py` module. How do I actually set that setting?

The reason for setting "**main**" is because I am using someone else's `pickle` file, and that file needs to refer to classes that are in the `__main__` module. So I need to make sure that I set the module in which the unpickling happens to be the "**main**" module, and also move the command line interface and other functions to that module.

Comment: "The reason for setting "`__main__`" is because I am using someone else's `pickle` file, and that file needs to refer to classes that are in the `__main__` module." - that usually means the pickle and/or the code that created the pickle are broken.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, the pickle is broken. But apparently that is how Fastai does it. I did not actually create the pickle file, just got it from one of the project team members. So I have to work with what I have. I actually have the module file--with classes--that the pickle refers to. I just need to call that from the `__main__` module, and I need to know how to set that attribute in a package.

Comment: Usually this is the module called as initial script from command line.